# Generate JWT after spring security kerberos authentication

Tags: spring-security, jwt, spring-security-kerberos

I would like to generate a JWT token after a kerberos authentication.
My kerberos authentication works very well. 
Here my spring security kerberos configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Value("${app.service-principal}")
private String servicePrincipal;

@Value("${app.keytab-location}")
private String keytabLocation;

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return authenticationManager();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(spnegoEntryPoint())
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .addFilterBefore(
            spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(authenticationManagerBean()),
            BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .authenticationProvider(kerberosAuthenticationProvider())
        .authenticationProvider(kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public KerberosAuthenticationProvider kerberosAuthenticationProvider() {
    KerberosAuthenticationProvider provider = new KerberosAuthenticationProvider();
    SunJaasKerberosClient client = new SunJaasKerberosClient();
    client.setDebug(true);
    provider.setKerberosClient(client);
    provider.setUserDetailsService(dummyUserDetailsService());
    return provider;
}

@Bean
public SpnegoEntryPoint spnegoEntryPoint() {
    return new SpnegoEntryPoint("/login");
}

@Bean
public SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter();
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    return filter;
}

@Bean
public KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider() {
    KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider provider = new KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setTicketValidator(sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator());
    provider.setUserDetailsService(dummyUserDetailsService());
    return provider;
}

@Bean
public SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator() {
    SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator ticketValidator = new SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator();
    ticketValidator.setServicePrincipal(servicePrincipal);
    ticketValidator.setKeyTabLocation(new FileSystemResource(keytabLocation));
    ticketValidator.setDebug(true);
    //ticketValidator.setHoldOnToGSSContext(true);
    return ticketValidator;
}

@Bean
public DummyUserDetailsService dummyUserDetailsService() {
    return new DummyUserDetailsService();
}

}
```

Is there a simple solution to generate a jwt token after this authentication? 
Following my internet search, I found nothing interesting.

Thanks for your answers !